# How do I print the elements of an array one at a time?

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

I have written the following code in C++.This is for a  program that generates a random sequence of letters and/or digits, displays them to the user one at a time for a second or so, and then asks the user to reproduce the sequence.It uses a queue to store the sequence of characters.I want to modify the code such that it prints the elements of an array one at a time.Please help me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

std::queue<int> myqueue;
int array[6];
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{

    array[i]=rand()%100;

    printf("\n%d", array[i]);

    if(i==5) 
    {
        printf("\n Reproduce the sequence again");
    }

}
```

Comment: Not really sure I follow, do you mean you want to clear the screen after each element has been displayed?

Comment: If you want portability use [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: Clearing the screen is a platform issue because the *standard* C++ language has no facilities for screens (not every platform is required to have a screen).

Comment: Do you want a delay after each number?  Do you want the program to *sleep* after each number?  Do you want the User to press Enter after each number?  Do you want the User to press any key after each number?  Please edit your post with the answers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you expect (I suppose a memory game), but let's have a look at this. I am using usleep, I'm sure something equivalent exists for Windows

```
#include <unistd.h> // Required for usleep
#include <iostream> // cin, cout, flush
#include <stdlib.h> // rand

int main () {

    int array[6]; // Note : This will only give you an array of digits, not letters

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {

        array[i]=rand()%100;

        // "\r" is a carriage return, it moves the writing to the beginning of the line
        std::cout << "\r" << array[i] << std::flush;

        // sleeps 1 second
        usleep(1000000);
    }


    printf("\r Reproduce the sequence again (use space to separate, enter to validate");
    std::string userAnswer;
    std::cin >> userAnswer;

    // parse userAnswer

}
```

Comment: With C++11 and beyond you can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for)

Comment: I'm not sure if C++11 is available, but that would be an excellent choice indeed :)

Comment: You also have to write numbers with fixed width, as writing `100` followed by `2` will show `200`.